# Border on CALayer appears incorrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, border, calayer

I have a CALayer which i a circle image, I am trying to add an external border to this. (shadows will not work for me here).  I have tried resizing the CALAyer and adding the border but the positioning appears incorrect, i do not want the shape to move, just a border to be added.

here is my code

```
CGFloat borderWidth = 10.0f;

    CGFloat xPos = cont.layer.frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat yPos = cont.layer.frame.origin.y;
    CGFloat contWidth = cont.layer.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat contHeight = cont.layer.frame.size.width;

    cont.layer.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, contWidth + borderWidth, contHeight + borderWidth);
    cont.layer.cornerRadius = contWidth / 2;
    cont.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
    cont.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: not 100% sure what you have going on here however you only seem to account for the border width once in this line .. cont.layer.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, contWidth + borderWidth, contHeight + borderWidth);
     perhaps you mean contWidth + borderWidth * 2  or some such depending on which way youre trying to go

Comment: i have given answer check it. Just add that line below your code.

Comment: My original layer moves position, i want it to remain in the same place and the border appears around the outside?

Comment: where is your answer?

Comment: so why mess with the frame? why not just simply only set the borderwidth, color and radius of the layer?

Comment: i want the border to appear on the outside of the layer image, which i thought was only possible to be on the inside (so covers up part of the image), so by increasing the frame size by the size of the border the whole image would be showing and non would be covered up by border

Comment: @geoBApp i have edited my answer. please check it. you require screen like i have uploaded right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Your code is correct.
Please add one line:

cont.clipsToBounds=YES

self.imgView1.layer.cornerRadius =self.imgView1.frame.size.width / 2;

self.imgView1.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];

self.imgView1.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;

self.imgView1.layer.masksToBounds=TRUE;

After this follow the steps:

1. Create another UIImageView and Place it above the first imageView.
2. Then increase height and width of secondImageView to 20.
3. set secondImageView center and FirstImageCenter equal(at same point).

and Write the Following code:

self.imgView2.layer.cornerRadius=self.imgView2.frame.size.width / 2;

self.imgView2.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];

self.imgView2.layer.borderWidth = 10.0f;

self.imgView2.layer.masksToBounds=TRUE;

Please do above steps it will solve your problem.

Now you will get output like this:

[image]

Comment: clipsToBounds is not working for CALayer, masksTobounds does, but not what I'm after. My original layer moves position, i want it to remain in the same place and the border appears around the outside?

Comment: i have done it using clipToBounds wait i will sharing screen shot

Comment: i have set border colour to blue. you requires this output or anything else. and clipToBounds is UIImageView property.

Comment: @geoBApp share your screen shot

Comment: this is what i'm trying to achieve, but the border covers some of the image, i want it to appear on the outside of the CALayer (image) so i don't loose any of the picture

Comment: i am sharing my code you can try it and let me know.

Comment: UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"i2.png"];  


    self.imgView1.image=img;

  
    CGFloat borderWidth = 10.0f;


    self.imgView1.layer.cornerRadius =self.imgView1.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.imgView1.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    self.imgView1.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    self.imgView1.clipsToBounds=TRUE;

Comment: if you want the full image then first you need to compress it.

Comment: yes, thats what i was trying, i've had no problem adding border, its to get it not to cut of any of the image (to be on the outside).

Comment: i got the answer. i will share it.

Comment: @geoBApp Try my answer. and if it solve your problem then inform me.

Comment: @geoBApp If you satisfied with my answer please up vote for this answer.